# The Grid table breaks the layout when adaptive and go outside the tag body

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

When adaptive, `.grid` goes beyond the body tag, thereby breaking the layout.
I want the `.grid` block to stretch to the width of the screen, and when adaptive, hide under the parent `.card` block, which provides a scroll inside itself.

HTML:

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="card">
<div class="grid">
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Title</p>
  
    <p>Content Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lime;
}

.wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
}


.card {
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

As I found out, if a piece of grid table code is executed separately, it works as expected. This is a bug in the flexbox grid. But how can I fix this in the current code?

Comment: Can i ask why you're using a flex as general structure and inside of inside a grid? You can make this design only in grid: nav (left), header (top), main (center), with a nested grid inside the header.

Comment: @pierfarrugia I tried to change the flex to grid, but for some reason it did not help. Perhaps I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I removed from `.wrapper` property `flex-grow: 1` and added `max-width: 100%; width: 100%`.

Comment: great... If you are using grid, try to use it for web layout, card layout... Use flex for example inside 1 cell of the grid. Lot easier to setup this way